# IOS: Storing,retrieving & calling Code blocks

Tags: ios, closures, nsdictionary, restkit

So I am using restkit for asynchronous calls and such, and felt the one of the best ways to handle possible connection issues was to have a requestManager Which holds a single an array of requests and it will keep looping through it and remove whenever they are successful, this way the payload for the request can be created and added to the manager and the rest of the app can continue without having to worry about returns or not unless it is a GET... Now my issue is that some of the requests are using closures or code Blocks as you will.

And i am having trouble wrapping my head around the syntax and usage of it properly. Especially when it comes to blocks.

This is how I plan to implement it...

so I first Make this Call

```
GameInfo *game = [[GameInfo alloc] init];

game.myWTFID = [playerInfo _wtfID];
game.opponentWTFID = [gameInfoObj GetOpponentWTFID];
game.gameType = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[gameInfoObj gameType]];
game.turnNumber = [gameInfoObj GetTurnNumber];
game.lastMove = [gameInfoObj GetGameID];

[[RequestPayload sharedRequestPayload] addPutRequestForObject : game withSerializationMapping : serializedGameMap forClass : [Game class] withBlock :^(RKObjectLoader *loader) 
 {
     [loader setObjectMapping:gameMap];
     loader.delegate = self;
     loader.onDidLoadResponse = ^(RKResponse *response) 
     {
         [game release];
     };
     loader.targetObject = nil;
     loader.backgroundPolicy = RKRequestBackgroundPolicyRequeue;
 }
 ];
```

here Is the Implementation

```
- ( void ) addPutRequestForObject : (id) object withSerializationMapping : (RKObjectMapping*) serialMapping forClass : (Class) class withBlock : ( void(^)(RKObjectLoader*) ) block 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    NSNumber *postType = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:1];

    [dict setObject:postType forKey:@"request"];
    [dict setObject:object forKey:@"data"];
    [dict setObject:serialMapping forKey:@"serialMapping"];
    [dict setObject:class forKey:@"class"];

    void (^ copyBlockLoader)(id,RKObjectMapping*) = Block_copy(block);
    [dict setObject:copyBlockLoader forKey:@"block"];
    Block_release(copyBlockLoader);


    [postType release];
    postType = nil;

    [_RequestsToInvoke addObject:dict];
}
```

and then within a for loop after going though each object in the array which will be a dictionary containing the needed information to do something like this.(apologies if this does not make sense it is highly contrived as the actual method is alot longer but the vital part i thought was here.)

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[dict objectForKey:@"serialMapping"] forClass:[dict objectForKey:@"class"]];
void(^block)(RKObjectLoader *) = [dict objectForKey:@"block"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] putObject:object usingBlock:block];
```

So my questions are

in the first snippet where i ask it to release the game object...Will that work? or will it result in a leak the game object is declared within the same scope as that call so the only pointer i have left is the one in the code block.

am i saving the block into the dictionary correctly?

and last does anyone have a better alternative? or spot something else with my implementation that needs correcting/modification?

Comment: Are you using ARC? If so, you don't have to worry about releasing the game object. Also, is the system you set up only to respond to the requests as they come back in?

Comment: @danielM: obviously not, because if he was using ARC, he wouldn't be able to use `release`

Comment: One thing that is definitely wrong is that `[game release]` inside that block. You should never release a local variable you didn't retain in the same scope.

Comment: it is allocated just above the function call with the code block, is that still wrong?I have edited it to show you what i am currently doing.